# how to trigger react native textInput's onSubmitEditing when i write 13 characters

Tags: react-native

i can't figure it out how to do that, some how after i put 13 number to textInput onSubmitEditing should run is there any way to do that ?

````
<Input
          placeholder={'Ürün ara'}
          value={barcodes}
          onChangeText={text => onChangeText(text)}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          autoFocus
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          contextMenuHidden={true}
          maxLength={13}
          style={{
            paddingRight: dimensions.width * 0.125,
            paddingLeft: dimensions.width * 0.03,
          }}
          onSubmitEditing={text => getir(text)}
        />
```
````

Comment: Please provide a little more details about your component. Basically, all you need to do is to check the length of your textInput and activate whatever you need when it reaches 13.

Comment: @MrBens that's all of it 

onSubmitEditing={(event) => {if (event.nativeEvent.text.length===13){
                                                getir(event.nativeEvent.text);}
 }}

i thought this sould work but it's not

Comment: What does onChangeText updates?

Comment: it updates barcode state